# Monocular camera calibration for Nao

Tags: calibration, nao, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I followed the tutorial for camera_calibration package but after I get

> opengl support available

nothing happens.

Here is the result of my rostopic list before running camera calibration:

```
/nao_camera/camera_info
/nao_camera/image_raw
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

And I then run camera_calibration

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.035 image:=/nao_camera/image_raw camera:=/nao_camera --no-service-check
```

Finally this is the program's output:

```
init done 
opengl support available
```

I checked if images were reaching /nao_camera/image_raw and it was the case.

So what is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187642/monocular-camera-calibration-for-nao/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was a problem coming from OpenCV. After recompiling the newest version the calibration worked well.

---

Originally posted by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) with karma: 3339 on 2014-08-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1